# Horizontally align images within a div

Tags: html, css, image, alignment

Would like to horizontally align multiple images and have them flow down the page if there are too many. (This is a mini gallery in the middle of a wordpress post).

After trying multiple code variations found on this site, I still can not get it working. However it works fine at JSFiddle...

**Links needed here here:**

[Working code at JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tzhsu/4/)

[Non-working code at my website](http://goo.gl/T7Ym6) (even though the exact same code is being used as above).

Is anyone able to assist me as to what's going wrong?

**HTML and CSS are evident in the first 'JSFiddle' link*

**Using latest version of wordpress*

**PROBLEM SOLVED:** *(can't answer my own question for another 8hrs due to being new)*

There is Auto Formatting and AutoText in wordpress that was automatically adding 'breaks' to the end of my image hyperlinks.

Added ".photographs br {display: none;}" to the CSS and it works fine!

Comment: you shouldnt add <br/> in your code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have `<br>` tags in between your images.  Remove them and it will fix itself.

Comment: Correct, deleted the br tags in chrome and it arrange perfectly.

Comment: The breaks are probably something that Wordpress adds by itself in it's "intelligent" coding.

Comment: In the html editor within wordpress, there definitely is no <br /> tags. It's being added automatically wordpress. A quick look on google and it seems to be happening to a few people.

Comment: @user1630422 while there may be a better solution, you can add `display:none` to the <br> tags within your photographs div for a quick fix.

Comment: Tomorrow I will try one or two plugins that remove WordPress's "auto text" and see if that works. Thanks for the hints!

Report back soon :-)

Comment: Added 
".photographs br { display: none; }" to my CSS and it worked a treat!

Answer (score 2):

remove `<br/>` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

**PROBLEM SOLVED!**

There is `Auto Formatting` or `AutoText` in `Wordpress` that was automatically adding `<br />` to the end of my image hyperlinks.

Added `.photographs br {display: none;}` to the `CSS`, and it works a treat.